# Remotely run Javascript function from external programs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am running two programs one which runs 24/7 coded in javascript which is running from a console in node.js. The other is written in Java and is a plugin. I am looking to run a function in the javascript program when something happens in the Java program. I am going to be putting data into the database in Java and reading from it in Javascript. I have thought about checking for updates in the database or just running the function every 5 minutes. However that seems like an inefficient way of doing it. I have tried googling and cannot find a good solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cheers @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan let me google it for you has been banned from stack overflow because it was judged rude. please do not try to use it in a detourned way. If the post do not comply with the rules, use the close/flag functionality.

Comment: Yes I could also just have closed it - I find that MUCH more rude than posting a google relying on my google-fu - please see update @GrégoryNEUT

Comment: @mplungjan So if your link hold the answer, extract it from here and post it as an answer :) Because of the next people won't have potentially the same result in your google link, or don't know what to look for precisely. Just my opinion so :) Enjoy your day